# Can Android Color List Selectors be cascaded?

Tags: android, android-selector

If I have a color list called color_list_1 like so:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <item android:color="#00FF00"/>
</selector>
```

I would like to be able to create another color list called color_list_2:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0000FF"/>
    <item android:color="@color/color_list_1"/>
</selector>
```

What this allows me to do is have a control, Foo, which uses color_list_1 for a color. Now I may want to create a subclass called AmazingFoo which I want to keep the same look as Foo except I also want to add a pressed color to it.

I have tried this but it seems when using color_list_2 as the color, the states are ignored inside color_list_1. This means the pressed state works (because it is in color_list_2 directly) but when it falls back to color_list_1 the focused state is always false so the default color is returned.

I know it isn't a problem with the control because using color_list_1 works perfectly. It is only when I cascade it inside another colorlist that all of the states return false.

Comment: You can't do that in the xml drawable. But, you could simply build the initial drawable at runtime in `Foo` and then change it in subclasses to add the new state(s).

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can modify ColorStateList objects in java, so even if my Foo class manually creates a ColorStateList object the subclass AmazingFoo would not be able to modify it to add its own state. It only has a constructor which takes all states and color pairings. Yes I could work around that by having each class provide the list of its own pairings which the subclass can grab to create its own but it all just seems like a hack.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Try using the a `StateListDrawable` instead which will have its state pointing to simple shape drawables filled with the current colors.